# How to correctly write new "event page" for chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In new chrome extension API "background pages" was replaced with "event pages" that are loaded only one on extension install and need to register callback that will be called by chrome on some events.

I want to create "event page" that will execute my code every second. I have created an extension with "manifest.json":

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name" : "myextension",
  "version" : "1.0.0",
  "background" : { "scripts" : [ "background.js" ], "persistent" : false }
}
```

and "background.js":

```
function onTimer()
{
  console.log( "on timer" );
}

function onStartup()
{
  console.log( "on startup" );
  window.setInterval( onTimer, 1000 );
}

console.log( "script load" );
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener( onStartup );
```

After i install extension, i can see "script load" in developer tools console, but not "on startup" and "on timer" :(. And after i close and reopen my browser, even "script load" is not display (that is expected). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `setInterval` -> `chrome.alarms`

Comment: @RobW "In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them an arbitrary amount more" <-- it seems that minimum distance between alarms is one minute, and i need to run a code every second :(

Comment: Running code eveny second means that the background page must be loaded all the time. Then you must use a background page, not an event page. (and what do you need to do every second? it must consume a lot of resources and can possibly slow down the browser.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Google Event Pages API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html):

> If your extension uses window.setTimeout() or window.setInterval(),
>   switch to using the alarms API instead. DOM-based timers won't be
>   honored if the event page shuts down.

Looks like event pages are trashing you setInterval() function.